# the alignment of char and char* in memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char, stack

Could you please help me to understand this:
if I define a main function as follow, how is the stack will be look like?

```
void main(void){
 char c1='A';
 char c2='B';
 char c3='C';
}
```

[Would it be like this(P1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx3df.gif)

[or this (P2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU6WQ.gif)

same question if change the function to:

```
void main(void){
char *a="ABC";
}
```

Comment: The stack will look like how the compiler chooses to. If a machine has stack at all. The compiler may optimize both code to `main() {}` as the variables are unused. It may place first variable on address 0x10 and the second in address 0xfffff00, because it want's to. The stack may go up or down. You can/need to specify architecture and compiler, compiler version with compiler options - you could then get an answer. Note that `void main(void)` is [invalid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: Wouldn't this be (at least in part) implementation-dependent?

Comment: Ex. on x86_64 with gcc8.2 no options the first code snipped - compiler places `c1` in address `rbp-1`, `c2` in `rbp-2` and `c3` in `rbp-3`. Substituting for `rbp` the value of 0x2c, that will make `c1` in `0x2b`, `c2` in `0x2a` and `c3` in `0x29` so the other way round then image `P1`. There is no `main` function address saved on the stack by the compiler. Code available on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1qZ7dg).

Comment: An optimizing compiler will eliminate dead code `char c1='A';
 char c2='B';
 char c3='C';`  same for `char *a="ABC";`.  [The question is moot](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x54vjte).

Comment: This question makes sense only the context of a particular compiler (real or imaginary/simplified for a classroom) or other C implementation. C can be implemented in many, many ways, with each compiler making its own decisions about how to arrange things.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's very helpful. Guess I'll need to learn more about how compiler works.

Comment: @chux I saw this video clip in network first run, but had forgotten about it. Thanks for digging it up!

Comment: Isn't there a rule for alignment in the standard?

Comment: @Swordfish I wouldn't want to bet on that.  The standard is intentionally written to be as machine agnostic as it possibly can, precisely to allow C to be implemented on as broad a set of architectures as possible.  About all the standard can (and should) say is that alignment is implementation defined.  If memory serves, `#pragma pack(1)` `struct foo { char a; int b; };` is likely to produce an odd byte aligned int with MSVC on x86.  Meanwhile, on 68K etc. `b` **must** be padded because odd byte access to ints will crash.

Comment: @dgnuff You are right: [§6.2.8/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.8p1): *An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type: stricter alignment can be requested using the _Alignas keyword.*